# Python.exe crashes when saving CMYK tif image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, cmyk

I'm having troubles only with CMYK tif images in PIL. The thing is that everything seems to be going fine, I can load the file, save it, but when I crop it and try to save it python.exe just hangs. Here's a rough transcript of my session:

```
>>> import os
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> os.listdir(".")
['CMYK_TIFF.tif', 'GRAYSCALE_TIFF.tif', 'RGB_TIFF.tif']
>>> im = Image.open("CMYK_TIFF.tif")
>>> im
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=CMYK size=4320x3240 at 0x2630B88>
>>> points = (12, 3, 44, 88)
>>> im = im.crop(points)
>>> im
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=CMYK size=32x85 at 02630B48>
>>> im.save("new_image.tif")
```

At this point python.exe just crashes. This is not an isolated issue, it happens consistenly at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PD: I'm using python 2.7.3 and PIL 1.1.7 in a windows 7 x64 OS.

PD2: Python crash dump:

```
Descripción (description)
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores (filepath to the application with errors):                 C:\Python27\python.exe
Firma del problema (problem signature)
Nombre de evento de problema (name of the event or problem):    APPCRASH
Nombre de la aplicación (application name): python.exe
Versión de la aplicación (aplication version):  0.0.0.0
Marca de tiempo de la aplicación (timestamp):   4f84a524
Nombre del módulo con errores (Name of the module with errors): MSVCR90.dll
Versión del módulo con errores (version of the module with errors): 9.0.30729.6161
Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores (module timestamp):  4dace4e7
Código de excepción (exception code):   c0000005
Desplazamiento de excepción (exception displacement):   000000000001e2e0
Versión del sistema operativo (OS version): 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Id. de configuración regional (regional configuration id):  11274
Información adicional 1:    3312
Información adicional 2:    3312c03e983672d704c6ef8ee1696a00
Información adicional 3:    b29d
Información adicional 4:    b29dcc8fc6f4d939931d139c4d9e8d31

Información adicional sobre el problema
Id. de depósito:    67567272
```

Comment: First, what happens if you hit ^C here? If that doesn't help, can you attach a debugger (or just re-run python under a debugger), break in while Python is hung, and post the backtrace? (If there's a bug in PIL's C code, which is plausible in this case, just debugging the Python won't help, except to narrow down exactly what cases trigger the C bug…)

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't appropiate. By hung up I mean crashes. I receive a message from windows telling me that python has unexpectedly stopped working. I'll edit my question

Comment: Also, which PIL version (and, while we're at it, which Python version, which platform, how did you install, and how did you get any dependencies)?

Comment: OK, if it crashes rather than hangs, you can get a crash dump without manually attaching a debugger. Please post the stack trace from that crash dump.

Comment: Also, does it happen with _every_ CMYK image, or just this one? If the latter, can you post the image anywhere? (For what it's worth, if I grab a random image, convert it to TIFF, then `im=Image.open('foo.tiff'); im.convert('CMYK'); im.save('foo-cmyk.tiff')` it works fine, but I have no idea whether it's because I have a different PIL version, a different image, or something else.)

Comment: I actually don't use Windows much, so this is off the top of my head, but I think if you've installed either Visual Studio or Debugging Tools for Windows, you've got something called "ADPlus" which you can use to change the crash dump settings for any app, like `adplus.vbs -crash -pn python.exe -o C:\MyDumps`, after which any crash will create a crash dump in `C:\MyDumps\` (you probably have to mkdir the directory first). It looks like Microsoft has a series of blog entries starting at http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/01/10/preparing-to-troubleshoot-part-one.aspx

Comment: One more thing: `crop` is a lazy function, which means it just stores a "next time someone tries to access the pixels, crop it" instruction instead of actually modifying the image. In your case, the actual crop happens at `save` time. Try adding a `im.load()` before the `save` to force the crop, and see whether it crashes in that function, or the `save` call. (It's also just barely possible you're running out of memory, and this will magically fix the problem by disposing of the huge original image…)

Comment: I found a dump, but it's in spanish. I'll post it anyway. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19548/discussion-between-pablo-mescher-and-abarnert)

Comment: Sorry, I was at lunch, then in a meeting. And now I've got another one, so I can't chat. Please try the other steps I asked you to do (find out if it's all CMYK images or just this one, post the image somewhere, and see whether calling `im.load()` before the `save` crashes). Also, we need the stack trace for the crashed thread out of the dump, not just the dump summary.

Comment: @abarnert load did the trick, post this as an answer so I can close the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crop` function is actually lazy, meaning the cropping doesn't happen until you try to access the pixels, which in your case happens during the `save`.

You can force it to happen eagerly by calling `load`:

```
>>> im = im.crop(points)
>>> im
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=CMYK size=32x85 at 02630B48>
>>> im.load()
<PixelAccess at 0x108d2ba70>
>>> im.save("new_image.tif")
```

I initially suggested this as a way to help debug the problem, because there are three things that could happen:

1. If `load` crashes, the problem is in forcing evaluation of the crop.
2. If `load` succeeds, but `save` crashes, the problem is in saving (certain) TIFF images.
3. If they both succeed… the first possibilities that come to mind are that you don't have enough memory to keep the cropped and uncropped versions around simultaneously, or there's a bug somewhere in the way `save` triggers evaluation of lazy functions.

Of course in option 3, if you're just trying to get past this for a one-shot task, you may not care about debugging further. But there's a good chance it'll pop up again with a different image, so if you're trying to build a program for wider use, it's better to continue debugging the problem (starting with getting the stack trace from a crash dump).

See [the docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) for more details on all of the functions described above.